# Как в элементе ListView расположить дочерние записи под родительскими

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Как в элементе `ListView` расположить дочерние записи под родительскими и возможно ли такое в принципе? А то по умолчанию `ListView` располагает дочерние записи в строчку, т.е. рядом с родительской записью располагается дочерняя, что в моем случае не совсем мне подходит.

Comment: Я думаю Вам подойдут [группы][1]


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.listview.groups(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Дело в том, что группы, это не совсем то, что нужно. Чтобы было более яснее приведу пример. 

Есть "некий заказ" который в процессе попадания до конечного потребителя может переживать несколько "стадий". Вот именно эти "стадии", я и хочу выводить в ListView под родительской записью, чтобы наглядно было видно все операции над конкретным заказом.

Comment: @sp7, не вижу проблем. Группа - заказ, а его дочерние итемы - стадии

Comment: В данном случае, в группах у меня предполагается хранить "заказы", по их статусу, например группа - "Завершенные заказы", группа - "Только что поступившие заказы" и т.д. Т.е. в итоге должно все выглядеть примерно следующим образом:

Например, в группе "Завершенные заказы" располагаются все завершенные заказы, у каждого заказа в этой группе, под его родительской записью располагаются ее дочерние, т.е. те операции которые производились над этим заказом и т.п.

В общем в идеале я хочу, чтобы иерархия была как в TreeView, но информацию можно было представить в табличном виде!

Comment: @sp7, тогда рекомендую сменить `winform` на `wpf`, т.к. стандартный `ListView winform` вроде ничего в этом направлении больше не умеет, а кастомизировать его (как и все winform'овское) очень не просто. Или же, как вариант, посмотреть в сторону другого контрола

Comment: В том то и суть, что нужно все это в WinForms сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что Вы ищете что то такое:

[image]

Код конечно нужно будет немного допилить, но думаю можно получить все что нужно.

Ссылка на статью: [Virtual Mode TreeListView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42110/Virtual-Mode-TreeListView).

Comment: Спасибо. Да примерно, что-то в этом духе.